# How to add padding to last view in RecyclerView, only if the RecyclerView is scrollable?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'd like to add bottom padding to the last view in a RecyclerView, but **only** if the RecyclerView is scrollable - in other words, if the last adapter item is completely visible with no scroll, do not add padding. I realized that from within onBindViewHolder, `findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()` will always return the previous item's position because the current view is not technically visible yet. I also tried an ItemDecorator but this also doesn't work, since these are added before the views and so we still wouldn't know whether the RecyclerView is scrollable or not. My ideal method would look something like this:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    ...
    if (position == items.size() - 1 && [is scrollable]) {
        ((MyViewHolder) viewHolder).addBottomPadding(...);
    }
}
```

That [is scrollable] bit is what I'm not sure of. Is there another way to accomplish this?

Comment: Not sure whether this will work, but you can try to use `boolean scrollable = canScrollVertically(-1) || canScrollVertically(1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so I have a solution for you :). 
The core concept is attaching a `viewTreeObserver OnGlobalLayoutListener` to the last item in the `onBind`. Then the `OnGlobalLayout` method of it will be invoked after the View has been measured which is critical for your requirement. Once it is called just calculate `y + itemViewHeight` and compare it to the `height of the RecyclerView`. To get this height you also have to attach an `OnGlobalLayoutListener` to the RecyclerView and then set the `Adapter with the height of it as parameter`. You may need to set an "empty" Adapter before your onGobalLayout gets called to prevent an error.

Two important things to remember:

**- Never forget to remove the OnGlobalLayoutListener

 - 
The code below is
   ugly and just a minimal viable product**

The Activity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    rvTest.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
    //maybe an adapter without content has to be provided so you won't get the error: no adapter attached skipping layout
    rvTest.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object: ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
        override fun onGlobalLayout() {
            rvTest.adapter = RvTestAdapter(this@MainActivity, rvTest.height)
            rvTest.viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this) //must remove! 
        }

    })
}
}
```

The Adapter:

```
class RvTestAdapter(val context: Context, val recyclerViewHeight: Int): RecyclerView.Adapter<TestViewHolder>() {
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int) = TestViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.vh_test, parent, false))

    override fun getItemCount() = 3

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TestViewHolder, position: Int) {
        if (position == 2) { //last position
            holder.itemView.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object : ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
                override fun onGlobalLayout() {
                    if (holder.itemView.y + holder.itemView.height  > recyclerViewHeight) {
                        Log.d("YESSSS", "WOOP WOOP")
                    }

                    holder.itemView.viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
                }

            })
        }
    }

}
```

(hope you don't mind Kotlin code)

Comment: Glad I could help you

Answer (score 4):

Add **android:clipToPadding** attribute to your view and give padding to your view that will scroll with recylerview item.

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
     />
```

Hope this will help